# Div to expand vertically, but be scrollable if it has filled its container

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, overflow

**UPDATE:**

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ld68qtx/) for testing.

---

An illustration of what I'd like to achieve: (Rows and columns are [Bootstrap 4 rows and columns](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ld68qtx/).)

[image]

- The page should only have scrollbars if the second row is already
  "fully compressed" (0 height) and still the header + first row +
  footer can't fit in the viewport.
- The second row doesn't have to fill
  in all remaining pale green place. It's height can be flexible.

Flexbox? Max-width? Overflow... How should I start? What could be a good solution?

HTML:

```
<div class="page">

  <div class="header">
    ...<br>...
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"> .... </div>
            <div class="card-body"> .... </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"> .... </div>
            <div class="card-body"> .... </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"> .... </div>
            <div class="card-body scrollable"> THIS <br> SHOULD <br> BE <br> THE <br> SCROLLABLE <br> CONTENT </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    ...
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.page {
  background-color: palegreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

div.header,
div.footer {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

div.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div.row {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

div.scrollable {
  /* ??? */
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup too please?

Comment: In your illustration picture, it doesn't show card headers. And then you mentioned "The page should only have scrollbars if the second row is already "fully compressed" (0 height) and still the header + first row + footer can't fit in the viewport". Also it seems like you have `scrollable` on `.card-body`. How can the second row get "fully compressed" then since there would be `card-header` left behind?

Comment: @ZimSystem: I have a working solution for your problem. The question I asked above is the only roadblock now.

Comment: @DavidLiang, you're right, sorry for this confusion, I wanted to simplify the problem as much as possible. I didn't think at first that later I would post the whole original markup with bootstrap cards. Please consider then also the card headers as "uncompressable" blocks, so they should always preserve their height and only `card-body scrollable` should get "compressed".

Comment: @tom: Oh sorry I answered your problem before I read this comment. My solution should work with/without card headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is how you calculate the height for the `<main>` and usage of `flex`, esp. `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`.

### `<header>`, `<main>` and `<footer>`

> The second row doesn't have to fill in all remaining pale green place. It's height can be flexible.

So I assume you want the `<header>` and `<footer>` always stay on top and bottom. Instead of regular absolute positioning approach, I want to explicitly set the heights for them, as well as for `<main>`.

#### HTML

```
<header>header</header>
<main class="container-fluid"></main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

#### SCSS

```
$custom-header-height: 3rem;
$custom-footer-height: 2rem;

header, footer {
    background-color: var(--gray);

    // In order to position the text to the center, like your picture
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header {
    height: $custom-header-height;
}

footer {
    height: $custom-footer-height;
}

main {
    // Calculate the height for main, which is 100% viewport height -
    // height of header - height of footer
    height: calc(100vh - #{$custom-header-height} - #{$custom-footer-height});
    background-color: var(--teal);
}
```

#### Result

[image]

This gives you the playground you can build stuff on.

### First Row

The first row is free to expand as high as its contents, but you don't want it to take up any free space. That's why you set `flex-grow: 0;`. Also when you resize the window and the space for first row is shrinking, you don't want the cards go over the row. That's why you set `flex-shrink: 0;`. We might as well use the shortcut `flex: 0 0 auto;` for those 2.

But in order to set that, the first row (as well as the second row) needs to be flexbox children. So we set `display:flex;` on its parent - `<main>`.

#### HTML

```
<header>header</header>
<main class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row first-row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

#### SCSS (In addition)

```
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.first-row {
    // I purposely make first row's background yellow so that you can see it
    background-color: var(--yellow);
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

### Second Row

The key here is to make the `<card>` not to grow when there is space, but shrink on limited space, which is the default of flexbox children: `flex: 0 1 auto`;

But again, in order to use that, its parent needs to `display: flex;`. Here the parent is `col-6` since we want to use bootstrap grid system.

#### HTML

```
<header>header</header>
<main class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row first-row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row second-row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                ...
                ...
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

#### SCSS (In addition)

```
.second-row {
    // I purposely make second row's background to be blue so that you can see it
    background-color: var(--blue);

    // Any column, class name starts as "col-"
    [class*="col-"] {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;

        // So that when the second row is compressed to 0, it doesn't show
        // the row completely.
        min-height: 0;

        .card {
            // flex-grow: 0;
            // flex-shrink: 1;
            // Might as well just set it
            // flex: 0 1 auto;
            // But this is the default of flexbox children so we don't need to set
            // it here.

            .card-body {
              overflow-y: auto;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Result

> The second row doesn't have to fill in all remaining pale green place. It's height can be flexible.

[image]

> An illustration of what I'd like to achieve

[image]

> The page should only have scrollbars if the second row is already "fully compressed" (0 height) and still the header + first row + footer can't fit in the viewport

[image]

### Notes

1. There is still a funkiness when the second row is fully compressed. The scrollbar is still hanging there and I don't know how to get rid of it.
2. The code can be simplified a little bit without usage of bootstrap grid system.

### Demo

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBqyxZ

Sorry for this lengthy post. If you want to know more about `flexbox`, here is a great guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would but a set the height (or max-height if you prefer) on the card and then set overflow to scroll.

```
<html>
 <div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    Dispassionate extraterrestrial observer citizens of distant epochs 
     permanence of the stars billions upon billions vastness is bearable only 
     through love brain is the seed of intelligence. 
  </div>
 </div>
</html>

<style>
 .box {
   width: 500px;
   overflow: scroll;
 }
</style>
```